# Ubuntu 14.04 grinding to a halt - found this command and it seems to help, what is it?

Tags: command-line, 14.04

As title says, laptop was grinding to a halt after a period of time.  I have the system monitor running and it seems to show memory use getting higher and higher.  I had a look around and found this command:

```
sudo sysctl -w vm.drop_caches=3
```

It seems to stop my system from grinding to a halt.  Couple of questions though (I'm a Linux noob):

What does the command do?
Why does it seem to help?

Answer (score 2):

The `sysctl` command allows you to read and/or write to your kernel parameters at runtime.  The `-w` switch indicates that you wish to write one of those parameters.  The list of parameters you can write to are stored as files under the `/proc/sys` directory tree.

As per ftp://ftp.alaska.edu/pub/sois/man/drop_caches.html, valid values for `drop_caches` are:

```
0 # default
1 # free pagecache
2 # free dentries, inodes
3 # free pagecache, dentries, inodes
```

[Kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt) on the `vm` file states that writing to it:

> Writing to this will cause the kernel to drop clean caches, as well as
>   reclaimable slab objects like dentries and inodes.  Once dropped, their
>   memory becomes free.
>
> This is a non-destructive operation and will not free any dirty
>   objects. To increase the number of objects freed by this operation,
>   the user may run `sync' prior to writing to /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches. 
>   This will minimize the number of dirty objects on the system and
>   create more candidates to be dropped.

Furthermore, it provides a warning:

> Use of this file can cause performance problems.  Since it discards
>   cached objects, it may cost a significant amount of I/O and CPU to
>   recreate the dropped objects, especially if they were under heavy use.
>   Because of this, use outside of a testing or debugging environment is
>   not recommended.

Running this command appears to help because it frees-up your memory.  But this command won't solve your problem by itself.  The next time your system is grinding to a halt, open a terminal and try running the `top` command to see what is using your memory.

Comment: +1 for "But this command won't solve your problem by itself. The next time your system is grinding to a halt, open a terminal and try running the top command to see what is using your memory."